# Why is SHA256withRSA Signature Different when Computed Byte-by-Byte versus All at Once?

Tags: java, inputstream, digital-signature

I have two sections of code using Java's "SHA256withRSA" [Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html). One approach is an InputStream decorator that updates the signature byte by byte via the read() method:

```
public class SigningInputStream extends InputStream {
    // Removed for brevity: declaration of useful objects

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        final int nextByte = source.read();
        try {
            sign.update((byte) nextByte);
        } catch (java.security.SignatureException e) {
            throw new IOException("Unknown exception while signing file", e);
        }

        return nextByte;
    }

    // Removed for brevity 
}
```

The other generates the signature all at once:

```
Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sign.initSign(privateKey);
        
sign.update(contents);
byte[] signature = sign.sign();
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);
```

The two approaches give me different results. I am still reading through the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#page-32) (I found linked from another SO question), but I don't think I'd fully understand it; why would the two methods of signing (byte-by-byte versus all at once) yield different signatures?

Comment: If `int nextByte` happens to be `-1`,  you must refrain from doing `sign.update((byte) nextByte)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show how your `SigningInputStream` is used. Thus, let us assume that it is read completely without any resets, e.g. like this:

```
SigningInputStream sigIS = new SigningInputStream(...);
while (sigIS.read() != -1);
```

In this case the loop above already hints at the problem: **If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, `read` returns the value `-1`.**

Thus, if your `final int nextByte = source.read()` is `-1`, you have to ignore this value because it is not part of the stream content:

```
public int read() throws IOException
{
    final int nextByte = source.read();
    if (nextByte != -1)
    [
        try {
            sign.update((byte) nextByte);
        } catch (java.security.SignatureException e) {
            throw new IOException("Unknown exception while signing file", e);
        }
    }

    return nextByte;
}
```

Comment: Here I thought I'd stumbled on some deep, dark corner of the Sha256+RSA algorithm when it was just a stupid novice mistake. Thanks for answering.